# Blank page after npm react build

Tags: reactjs, build

After waiting for the terminal to compile my app and create de /dist folder, when i tried to open up the index.html inside, I was faced with a blank screen and I dont know what to do.

Package.json

```
"name": "client",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module", 
  "start_url": ".",
  "homepage": ".",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host",
    "build-css": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/index.css -o ./dist/output.css",
    "build": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/index.css -o ./dist/output.css && tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview --host"
```

App.tsx

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar/>
    <div className="app-body ">
      <Sidebar/>
      <Routes>
          <Route path="login/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route element={<RequireAuth/>}>
                      <Route path="home/" element={<Home />} />
                      <Route path="form/" element={<Form />} />
                      <Route path="EsqueciSenha/" element={<EsqueciSenha />} />
                      <Route path="ferias/" element={<Ferias />} />
                      <Route path="excecao/" element={<Excecao />} />
                      <Route path="logexcecao/" element={<LogException />} />
                      <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
                      <Route path="logchanges/" element={<LogChanges/>}/>
                      <Route path="sabado/" element={<Sabado/>}/>
          </Route> 
      </Routes>
    </div>
      
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Does somebody know's what can I do?

Comment: Check the logs, and browser console log, first.